# Some variable is undefined after deployment (Vue)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I'm working on a Vue, TypeScript, Nuxt (SRR) project.

I found that there's some input field that shows `undefined` after deployment but works just fine on localhost.

I'm trying to find the weird stuff in my code but I don't think I'm doing anything weird.

`component.vue`

```
<input
  :type="passwordFieldType"
  placeholder="Enter your password here"
  v-model="password"
/>
```

`component.ts`

```
@Component
export default class login extends Vue {
  passwordFieldType: string = "password";
  password: string = "";
```

What could be the possible reason for getting undefined after deployment?

Answer (score 0):

I already have the answer. It seems to be a Bootstrap bug. I was using a b-input tag, and when I removed it and redeployed, the 'undefined' issue disappeared.